File signature not ASTM-E57 (ErrorBadFileSignature)
I have an issue when I try to read a written e57 file using "e57.write_scan_raw" (pye57 library):

File signature not ASTM-E57 (ErrorBadFileSignature)

Here is the code used to write the e57 file:
import pye57
import numpy as np

def spherical_to_cartesian(range_, azimuth, elevation):
    """Convert spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates."""
    x = range_ * np.cos(elevation) * np.cos(azimuth)
    y = range_ * np.cos(elevation) * np.sin(azimuth)
    z = range_ * np.sin(elevation)
    return x, y, z

# Define input and output file names
input_file = 'M_0559.e57'
output_file = 'M_0559_rewritten.e57'

# Open the E57 file for reading
e57_read = pye57.E57(input_file)

# Read scan data at index 0
data_raw = e57_read.read_scan_raw(0)

# Check available fields
print("Available fields in data_raw:", data_raw.keys())

# Convert spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates
if all(field in data_raw for field in ['sphericalRange', 'sphericalAzimuth', 'sphericalElevation']):
    range_ = data_raw['sphericalRange']
    azimuth = data_raw['sphericalAzimuth']
    elevation = data_raw['sphericalElevation']

    cartesianX, cartesianY, cartesianZ = spherical_to_cartesian(range_, azimuth, elevation)

    # Add Cartesian coordinates to data_raw
    data_raw['cartesianX'] = cartesianX
    data_raw['cartesianY'] = cartesianY
    data_raw['cartesianZ'] = cartesianZ
else:
    print("Spherical coordinate fields are missing from data_raw.")

# Open a new E57 file for writing
e57_write = pye57.E57(output_file, mode='w')

# Ensure data_raw has all required fields
required_fields = ['cartesianX', 'cartesianY', 'cartesianZ', 'intensity', 'rowIndex', 'columnIndex']
for field in required_fields:
    if field not in data_raw:
        data_raw[field] = np.zeros_like(data_raw['sphericalRange'])

# Write the scan data to the new file
e57_write.write_scan_raw(data_raw)

print(f"File '{input_file}' has been successfully read and rewritten to '{output_file}'.")


How can I solve this?
